# How to write a logout application for android?

Tags: android, json, authentication, logout

I have developed an application which takes user name and password from user and send them to localhost. Localhost then sends a number back which is parsed by JSON. However, now I need to implement a log-out piece of code to log the users out.

How am I gonna do that?

Comment: Why don't you just send them back to the log in activity and `finish()` all others?

Comment: great idea, can u illustrate it with codes?

Answer (score 1):

From the non-login activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this,Login.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```